# Stability (equilibrium) condition in M/M/1 queue with both open and closed classes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

> Mixed queueing network models are those in which some classes are
> open and some are closed.

[image]

In the example network illustrated above, classes A and B are open and depart from the network after CPU queue with some probability, Classes C and D are closed and loop over CPU queue which is M/M/1.

I already know that if O is the set of **open** classes that enter CPU with $\lambda_i$ rate for each i $\in$ O and get service with rate $\mu'$ (which is affected by closed classes and not equal to the actual service rate of the queue), the stability condition if $\rho < 1$:

$\sum_{i \in O}\frac{\lambda_i}{\mu'} < 1$,

meaning that closed classes do not affect the instability of the queues they enter.

I don't remember where I saw it first and need solid proof or reference to a book or paper to back it up. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I don't know of a reference, but the intuition is easy to explain: as the number of open-class jobs in the system goes up, the rate at which they *actually* get service gets closer and closer $\mu$, because if $99\%$ of the jobs are from open classes, then we're almost always working on one of those jobs, and the system behaves almost like one with no closed classes. So states with sufficiently many jobs are recurrent, and therefore all states are recurrent.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I have to make it work out myself. I'm going with something similar to this intuition but with closed classes considered as vacations.